# Find a URL in content and make that URL clickable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, hyperlink

My content sometimes include URL for example in that URL(http://mobile.yazilimsozluk.com/konudetail.htm?9748) content a URL but it is not clickable.
  How can I do this clickable with javascript or css?Data come from API,I can not fix it.I must fix that in view with CSS or jquery

Comment: You can put you link inside <a>URL<a/> and this will make it a clickable link

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links

Comment: Please provide an example as per [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div').html($('div').html().replace(/(https?:\/\/.+?)(?:\s|$)/ig, '<a href="$1">$1</a> '));
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This searches all DIV content for URLs and replaces them by a corresponding anchor tag.
Please note that the RegExp is very simple and needs optimization before being used in production.

Comment: thanks @Quagaar it works but it add end of url   </a></p>    http://mobile.yazilimsozluk.com/konudetail.htm?9748 you can click here to see </a></p> at the end of url

Comment: @user1688401 This is only an example and has to be adapted to your specific requirements. You should narrow down the set of processed elements to only match the ones containing the content to modify. Also remember to optimize the RegExp that detects the URLs.

Comment: Perhaps these can also be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links